# CSS Overflow - Bottom Assignment Issue (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My apologies for not being able to be more descriptive in the title (suggestions for editing it are welcomed...)

I have designed a Team Page made up of a grid of images. I have laid it out to be responsive in Bootstrap 3.

When the consumer clicks the 'more' tab next to the image, a hidden DIV appears below the image containing more information about that team member.

The problem that I am having is that the DIV that appears shows all of the content of the DIV, but the background color (and another DIV that serves as a close button) stops at the bottom of the row directly beneath the row that was clicked on.

**http://jsfiddle.net/LL39h/**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="staff-page" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 zindex10">
            <img src="https://www.mrs.org.uk/img/blank_profile[bw].jpg" width=190 />
            <h3>Jane Doe<strong>Job Title</strong></h3>
            <a href="#" class="bio-show"><span class="moreorless"></span></a>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie dui vitae libero pellentesque, quis accumsan enim tincidunt. Nam porta felis ipsum, nec vehicula massa placerat feugiat. Etiam at erat et neque fermentum accumsan. Nulla sit amet augue pellentesque, condimentum diam eget, vestibulum eros.</p>
                <p>Nam fermentum eros non turpis suscipit fermentum. Aenean vitae convallis eros. Aliquam lorem odio, pulvinar nec interdum at, laoreet vitae enim.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:hugh.collins@mbsvalue.com" target="_blank">employee@employer.com</a></p>
                <p>+1.555.555.5555</p>
                <a href="#" class="bio-hide"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#staff-page div {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 190px; position: relative; overflow: visible;}

#staff-page {overflow:visible;}

.bio-show, .bio-show:hover {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.moreorless {padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;}
.moreorless:after {content: "more"; }
.bio-full .moreorless:after {content: "less"; }
.bio-hide {position:absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height:30px; background: #B5B5B5 url(../images/arrow-up.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;}
#overlay {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #000; filter:alpha(opacity=70); -moz-opacity:0.7; -khtml-opacity: 0.7; opacity: 0.7; display: none; z-index: 20;}
.zindex10 {z-index: 10;}
.zindex30 {z-index: 30;}
.clear {clear: both;}

/* For mobile screen */
#staff-page div:nth-of-type(even) {background-color: #f1f1f1; color: #333;}
#staff-page div:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color: #ECA833; color: #fff;}
#staff-page img {float: left;}
#staff-page h3 {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:18px; font-variant:small-caps; text-transform:lowercase; position:relative; top:80px; left:20px;}
#staff-page h3 strong {display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; font-variant:normal; text-transform:none;}
#staff-page .bio-show {display:block; position: absolute; width:95px; height:30px; top:160px; left: 190px; background:#D75401 url(../images/arrow-down.png) 10px 55% no-repeat; line-height: 30px;}
#staff-page .bio {padding: 30px; display: none; clear: both; background: inherit; color: inherit; position: relative; overflow: visible;}
#staff-page .bio-full {background:#b5b5b5 url(../images/arrow-up.png) 73px 55% no-repeat!important;}
#staff-page div:nth-of-type(even) img {float: right;}
#staff-page div:nth-of-type(even) h3 {float: right; right:20px; left:auto; text-align: right;}
#staff-page div:nth-of-type(even) .bio-show {display: block; right:190px; left: auto; background:#D75401 url(../images/arrow-down.png) 73px 55% no-repeat; text-align: right;}

/* For medium/small screen */    
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /*evens*/
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n), #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-1) {background: #f1f1f1; color: #333;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n) img, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-1) img {float: right;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n) h3, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-1) h3 {float:right; right:20px; left: auto; text-align: right}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n).bio-show, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-1) .bio-show {right: 190px; left: auto; background:#D75401 url(../images/arrow-down.png) 10px 55% no-repeat;}
    /*odds*/
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-2), #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-3) {background: #ECA833; color: #fff;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-2) img, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-3) img {float: left;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-2) h3, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-3) h3 {float:left; left:20px; text-align: left;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-2) .bio-show, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(4n-3) .bio-show {left: 190px; background:#D75401 url(../images/arrow-down.png) 10px 55% no-repeat;}
}

/* For large screen */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    /*evens*/
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n), #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-1), #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-2) {background: #f1f1f1; color: #333;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n) img, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-1) img, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-2) img {float: right;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n) h3, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-1) h3, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-2) h3 {float:right; right:20px; left: auto; text-align: right}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n) .bio-show, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-1) .bio-show, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-2) .bio-show {right: 190px; left: auto; background:#D75401 url(../images/arrow-down.png) 10px 55% no-repeat;}
    /*odds*/
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-3), #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-4), #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-5) {background: #ECA833; color: #fff;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-3) img, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-4) img, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-5) img {float: left;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-3) h3, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-4) h3, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-5) h3 {float:left; left:20px; text-align: left;}
    #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-3) .bio-show, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-4) .bio-show, #staff-page  div:nth-of-type(6n-5) .bio-show {left: 190px; background:#D75401 url(../images/arrow-down.png) 10px 55% no-repeat;}
}
```

Thanks in advance. This one really has me stumped.

Comment: .bio {height:auto!important;} this fixes the issue at hand. It's best to put the code in your question. There's likely a height somewhere else, but this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.bio {height:auto!important;}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LL39h/2/

There's something in your current css adding a height because it doesn't work without the !important.

Comment: That was exactly it. There was a nested div style. Thank you so much. Sometimes you look at things far too long to see something obvious.